# Get the current ViewController in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios, maui

I am porting a Xamarin Forms code that I had to .NET MAUI, but the code I have there to get the current view controller does not work, how do I get the current ViewControler in MAUI

Relevant code here: [Using UIDocumentPickerViewController in Xamarin forms as a dependency service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49966712/using-uidocumentpickerviewcontroller-in-xamarin-forms-as-a-dependency-service)

Relevant Xamarin Forms(iOS) code:

```
public UIViewController GetCurrentUIController()
{
    UIViewController viewController;
    var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
    if (window == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    if (window.RootViewController.PresentedViewController == null)
    {
        window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows
                 .First(i => i.RootViewController != null &&
                             i.RootViewController.GetType().FullName
                             .Contains(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform).FullName));
    }

    viewController = window.RootViewController;

    while (viewController.PresentedViewController != null)
    {
        viewController = viewController.PresentedViewController;
    }

    return viewController;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending a good amount of time porting this code, I realised that the relevant namespaces that were available in Xamarin Forms are now either internal or not there anymore, so I spent some time searching on what's the right way to do this with MAUI which again I did not find, but after some snooping into [this Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/platform-helpers?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=macios) I realised that the ApplicationModel's Platform class has exactly what I need,

```
var currentViewController = Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.GetCurrentUIViewController();
```

Adding this here so someone else does not have a waste an hour or two on this simple thing :)